# Cannot sign apk with old certificate

Tags: android, md5, signature, jarsigner

The current version of my apk in Android Play is from 23.01.2011. At that time
it was possible to create a key without using algorithms in the options.

From 08.2012 I had to create a new key store using the options

```
-sigalg MD5withRSA -keyalg RSA -keysize 1024
```

and sign my apk with jarsigner given

```
-sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1
```

Since then I am signing my apk in this way but never try to upload a new version
in Google market until now.

It turns out that the signature although I use the same text to create the key, is not the same as the old one.

Although I have the old key store I guess I cannot use it anymore to sign the 
apk with it to match the same signature as the one in the market, some tries result in unsigned apk.

Is there any possibility to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found! 
Just another try with the old key store giving only the option SHA1, that is

-digestalg SHA1

and the apk is again signed with the old certificate! 
I could upload the new version in Google play.